# Justify x-axis labels to align with x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm hoping to justify my x-axis labels so that they all start right along the x-axis rather than being center-justified. Here's my code:

```
ggplot(data=AllLogs, aes(x=Stand_Type, fill=OccupiedUnoccupied)) +
 geom_bar(stat="count", position=position_dodge()) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Here's what I get. [image: Stand Type Counts Grouped by Log Occupation Status]

Comment: `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much!